# PHP: ошибка вывода ссылок пагинации

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте товарищи!

У меня проблема с выводом пагинации. Запрос ищет в БД строки соответствующие вводимому в строку поиска, выводит результат, но отображаемое число ссылок в блоке пагинации не соответствует количеству реальных страниц. Например, поиск выдал только одну строку — следовательно, одна страница, а выводится число соответствующее общему количеству страниц и строк.

Код контроллера:

```
public function searchAction() {
    $pagination = new Pagination($this->route, $this->model->feedbackCount(), 5);
    $vars = [
        'pagination' => $pagination->get(),
        'search' => $this->model->feedbacksSearch($this->route),
    ];
    $this->view->render('Результаты поиска', 0, 0, 0, $vars);
}
```

Код модели:

```
public function feedbacksSearch($route, $search = [])
{
    $max = 5;
    $params = [
        'termin' => $_POST['termin'],
        'max' => $max,
        'start' => (($route['page'] ?? 1) - 1) * $max,
    ];
    return $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM `feedbacks` WHERE `email` LIKE :termin ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT :start, :max', $params);
}
```

Куда копать — вообще не соображу…

Вот класс пагинации:

```
namespace App\Core;

class Pagination
{
    private $max = INF; // 10
    private $route;
    private $current_page;
    private $total;
    private $limit;

    public function __construct($route, $total, $limit = 5) // 5
    {
        $this->route = $route;
        $this->total = $total;
        $this->limit = $limit;
        $this->amount = $this->amount();
        $this->setCurrentPage();
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $links = null;
        $limits = $this->limits();
        $html = '<ul>';
        for ($this->amount = null, $page = $limits[0]; $page <= $limits[1]; $page++) {
            if ($page == $limits[0] or $page == $limits[1] or abs($page - $this->current_page) < 3) { // 3
                if ($page == $this->current_page) {
                    $links .= $this->amount = '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
                } else {
                    $links .= $this->amount = $this->generateHtml($page);
                }
            } else {
                if ($this->amount == '<li>...</li>' or $this->amount == null) {
                    $links .= $this->amount = null;
                } else {
                    $links .= $this->amount = '<li>...</li>';
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $links . '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }

    private function generateHtml($page, $text = null)
    {
        if (!$text) {
            $text = $page;
        }
    
        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'admin') !== false) {
            $prefix = 'admin/';
        } else {
            $prefix = null;
    }
    
        return '<li>
                    <a href="/' . $prefix . $this->route['controller'] . '/' . $this->route['action'] . '/' . $page . '">' . $text . '</a>
                </li>';
    }

    private function limits()
    {
        $left = $this->current_page - round($this->max / 2); // 2
        $start = $left > 0 ? $left : 1;
        if ($start + $this->max <= $this->amount) {
            $end = $start > 1 ? $start + $this->max : $this->max;
        } else {
            $end = $this->amount;
            $start = $this->amount - $this->max > 0 ? $this->amount - $this->max : 1;
        }
        return array($start, $end);
    }

    private function setCurrentPage()
    {
        if (isset($this->route['page'])) {
            $currentPage = $this->route['page'];
        } else {
            $currentPage = 1;
        }
        $this->current_page = $currentPage;
        if ($this->current_page > 0) {
            if ($this->current_page > $this->amount) {
                $this->current_page = $this->amount;
            }
        } else {
            $this->current_page = 1;
        }
    }   

    private function amount()
    {
        return ceil($this->total / $this->limit);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->model->feedbackCount()` каким образом считает число элементов?

Comment: `public function feedbackCount()
{
  return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `feedbacks`');
}`

Comment: ну вот и ответ на ваш вопрос. кол-во элементов вы считаете без фильтра по email, а данные берёте с учётом фильтра

Comment: Это общая функция для всех случаев. Т. е. нужно сделать отдельную или как-то дополнить в модели?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить это в моём случае?

Comment: Очевидно же, подставить в запрос `feedbackCount()` конструкцию `WHERE email LIKE :termin`

Comment: Если вот так: public `function feedbackCount()
 {
  return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `feedbacks` WHERE email LIKE :termin');
 }` то ссылки пагинации вообще не выводятся

Comment: смотрите класс `Pagination`. Может у вас кол-во элементов меньше чем кол-во элементов на странице

Comment: Добавил класс пагинации в вопрос. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Он нормально работает просто в списках, а когда поиск тогда беда

Comment: Скажите, а вы *точно* не знаете для чего нужна переменная  $params при вызове $this->db->all()?

Comment: `public function all($sql, $params = [])
 {
  $result = $this->query($sql, $params);
  return $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 }`

Comment: я не спрашивал, какой код у этой функции. Я спрашивал, понимаете ли вы, зачем пишете  $params при вызове этой функции в feedbacksSearch

Comment: Ну так ведь параметры если используются в запросе

Comment: очень хорошо. в запросе `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM feedbacks WHERE email LIKE :termin` *тоже* используются параметры

Comment: Вот так, к сожалению, выдаёт ошибку `public function feedbackCount($search = [])
 {
  $params = [
   'email' => $_POST['termin'],
  ];
  return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `feedbacks` WHERE email LIKE :termin', $params);
 }` Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 column index out of range in…

Comment: надо все-таки разобраться, что такое $params и что в нее надо писать

Comment: Вот так считает правильно: `public function feedbackCount($search = [])
 {
  $params = [
   'termin' => $_POST['termin'],
  ];
  return $this->db->col('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `feedbacks` WHERE email LIKE :termin', $params);
 }` но при переходе на следующую страницу пишет как будто сообщений нет и выводит ошибки — `Notice: Undefined index: termin in /FeedbackController.php on line 67
Notice: Undefined index: termin in /FeedbackModel.php on line 28
Notice: Undefined index: termin in /FeedbackModel.php on line 72`

Comment: Параметры не сохраняются почему-то(